# How to merge 2 columns in a file alternatively?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, awk, solaris

How to merge 2 columns in a file alternatively? See below example.

inputfile:

```
sam    jam
tommy  bond
```

expected_output:

```
sam
jam
tommy
bond
```

Comment: `tr -s \ \\t \\n <infile` though your shell might not like those - you can always use literal space, tab and newline inside single quotes.

Comment: @don_crissti, POSIXly: `tr -s '[:blank:]' '[\n*]'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply with **`awk`**:

```
awk '{ print $1 ORS $2 }' file
```

- `$1` and `$2` - are the 1st and 2nd field respectively
- `ORS` -  Output Record Separator. The initial value of `ORS` is the string "`\n`" (i.e., a newline character)

---

The output:

```
sam
jam
tommy
bond
```

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives:

With awk :

```
$ awk '$1=$1' OFS="\n" file1
sam
jam
tommy
bond
```

This solution will work with any number of fields per row:

```
$ cat file2
one two three
four five
six seven eight nine

$ awk '$1=$1' OFS="\n" file2
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
```

`OFS` is the Output field separator.
`$1=$1` forces awk to "recalculate" each record ($0) using the OFS

Just for fun bellow a sed alternative that will also work for any number of fields per line:

```
$ sed -r 's/[ ]+/\n/g' file2
```

Answer (score 1):

For data on ~/z1, this command:

```
xargs -n1 < ~/z1
```

produces:

```
sam
jam
tommy
bond
```

On a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-4-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
xargs (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
```

and:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: SunOS, 5.11, i86pc
Distribution        : Solaris 11.3 X86
bash GNU bash 4.1.17
xargs - ( /usr/bin/xargs, 2016-04-10 )
```

The *xargs* command takes tokens from STDIN, up to n at a time (1 in this case), and provides the token as the argument to the command, defaulting to *echo*.

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Answer (score 0):

`` echo `paste -s file` | tr ' ' '\n' ``

or

`paste -s file | fmt -1`

or

`cat file | xargs -n1`

For your special case, no need to bother those programmatic commands, like `awk` or `sed`. Simple commands as above are enough.